# Error logging in when using Spring Security's "Remember Me" option

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm using Grails 1.3.4 and Spring Security Core 1.0.1.

If I choose the option "remember me" when I login sometimes when I load the page again it gives this error:

```
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver Error executing tag <g:render>: Error executing tag <sec:ifLoggedIn>: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed at D:/Workspace/steer/grails-app/views/templates/_header.gsp:18 at D:/Workspace/steer/grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp:29
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>: Error executing tag <sec:ifLoggedIn>: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed at D:/Workspace/steer/grails-app/views/templates/_header.gsp:18 at D:/Workspace/steer/grails-app/views/layouts/main.gsp:29
at D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_layouts_main_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_layouts_main_gsp:66)
at D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_layouts_main_gsp$_run_closure2.doCall(D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_layouts_main_gsp)
at D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_layouts_main_gsp.run(D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_layouts_main_gsp:75)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <sec:ifLoggedIn>: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed at D:/Workspace/steer/grails-app/views/templates/_header.gsp:18
at D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_templates__header_gsp.run(D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_templates__header_gsp:35)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
at D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_templates__header_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_templates__header_gsp:22)
at D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_templates__header_gsp$_run_closure1.doCall(D__Workspace_steer_grails_app_views_templates__header_gsp)
at grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityTagLib$_closure6.doCall(SecurityTagLib.groovy:130)
... 5 more
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

**_Hearer.gsp**

```
        <%@ page import="com.mycompany.myapp.partymodel.roles.SystemUserRole" %>
    <sec:ifLoggedIn>
    <%
    def userId = session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT?.authentication?.principal?.id
    def userDetails = SystemUserRole.get(userId)
     %>
    <div class="mast_head">
        <ul>
            <li>Welcome ${userDetails?.party?.firstName}</li>
            <li> | </li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "systemUserRole", action: "editprofile")}">Profile</a></li>
            <li> | </li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "systemUserRole", action: "changepassword")}">Edit Password</a></li>
            <li> | </li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "logout", action: "index")}">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </sec:ifLoggedIn>
    <div id="grailsLogo" class="logo">
        <a href="http://www.mycompany.in/"><img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'mycompany_trans.png')}" alt="Grails" border="0" height=67 /></a>
    </div>
```

**LayoutTagLib.groovy**

```
        package com.mycompany.myapp.layout
    import  com.mycompany.myapp.trips.Trip

    class LayoutTagLib {
        static namespace = "my"

          def header = { attrs ->
            Trip.withNewSession {
              sec.ifLoggedIn() {
                out << "<div class="mast_head">
        <ul>
            <li>Welcome ${userDetails?.party?.firstName}</li>
            <li> | </li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "systemUserRole", action: "editprofile")}">Profile</a></li>
            <li> | </li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "systemUserRole", action: "changepassword")}">Edit Password</a></li>
            <li> | </li>
            <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "logout", action: "index")}">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>"
              }
            }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a restriction about using that kind of tags in `layouts` since it's processed by SiteMesh after the hibernate session is commited.

The solution is to wrap this in a session (`withNewSession` closure of a domain class). Something like:

**LayoutTagLib is a TagLib, you can create with command create-taglib**

```
grails create-tag-lib com.app.layout.LayoutTagLib
```

**Important:** Replace the "SomeDomain" with any existing domain class of your application.

```
class LayoutTagLib {
  static namespace = "my"

  def header = { attrs ->
    SomeDomain.withNewSession {
      sec.ifLoggedIn() {
        out << "Logged In"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `out` is the html that will be printed in the page. So change it with whatever you have in your header template.

Then you have a **_header.gsp** correct? Just replace the `<sec:ifLoggedIn>` block with the call of your taglib.

```
<my:header />
```

**EDIT:**

You need to wrap your query's inside the `withNewSession`. And also remove the content from your header, just calling the taglib instead. To get the user data you can use the `springSecurityService`.

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.layout
import  com.mycompany.myapp.trips.Trip

class LayoutTagLib {
    //dependency injection of the plugin service
    def springSecurityService

    static namespace = "my"

      def header = { attrs ->

        Trip.withNewSession {

          sec.ifLoggedIn() {

            def userId = springSecurityService.currentUser.id
            def userDetails = SystemUserRole.get(userId)

            //better transform this in a private method or a template!
            out << """<div class="mast_head">
              <ul>
                <li>Welcome ${userDetails?.party?.firstName}</li>
                <li> | </li>
                <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "systemUserRole", action: "editprofile")}">Profile</a></li>
                <li> | </li>
                <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "systemUserRole", action: "changepassword")}">Edit Password</a></li>
                <li> | </li>
                <li><a href="${createLink(controller: "logout", action: "index")}">Sign Out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>"""              
           }
         }
      }
}
```

**_header.gsp**

```
<my:header/> <!-- This line will call your taglib!! -->
<div id="grailsLogo" class="logo">
        <a href="http://www.mycompany.in/"><img src="${resource(dir:'images',file:'mycompany_trans.png')}" alt="Grails" border="0" height=67 /></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: do i need to wrap with every domain class?

Comment: No, just one. the closure is the same for all.

Comment: Please explain a bit.. where i need to put this code.. I am New to grails... 

Step by Step answer is much appreciated.- Thank you..

Comment: I have updated question.
if i replace out (thml that wiil be printed in page) it gives error..